# Shiny Starter Pokemon on Fire Red using a GBA Emulator on Android

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I'm running Pokemon Fire Red on an Android phone using "My Boy!" emulator. Is it possible to get a shiny starter pokemon (Charmander) by reseting the game everytime I choose the starter pokemon? (I saved the game right before chosing it).

I made this question because I read on the Internet that it's not possible to get a shiny starer pokemon by reseting the game if you're using an emulator, because the interal code that determines whether if a pokemon is shiny or not does never reset.

Comment: Related: [Will shiny Pokemon appear when playing Pokemon on an emulator?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276885/will-shiny-pokemon-appear-when-playing-pokemon-on-an-emulator)

Comment: Well i was using save states to get a shiny Eevee as my starter in Blazing Emerald rom hack and i got my shiny Eevee, it took me thirty minutes to get my shiny so it technically works but i guess you also need some luck. hope this was hopeful in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you reset the game.

Most emulators offer what is called "save states". Save states contain the entire memory dump of a game, unlike regular save games which only contain what the developer believes is important for the game.

Save states are particularly popular among emulator users, because they offer a way to cheat, such as resetting a particular move in combat.

In this case, the save state will contain the RNG (Random Number Generator) which a regular save game would not; why keep the RNG in memory, if you can generate a new one every time you launch the game? Of course, this also means you cannot simply load a save state to improve your chances of getting a shiny Pokémon, you'll have to reload a regular save game instead.

In other words: you'll have to quit the game, launch it again, then load the save game from within the in-game menu.

Comment: If you want to know more about RNGs, [here's an interesting read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22723644/1169228). It's very technical, but it also explains why "random" numbers aren't really random.

Comment: So I'll just have to exit the game and open it again or quit the game, close the application (My Boy!) open again the emulator and enter the game?

Comment: You probably won't have to close your emulator. Most emulators should have a "Reset" option, which basically just reboots the game. Not to be confused with reloading a save game.