# Will shiny Pokemon appear when playing Pokemon on an emulator?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-third-generation

I'm playing the original Ruby (mugs version) on My boy! emulator for android and I am seriously considering looking for Shinies BUT, are there shinies in roms?

Or does the RNG process that determines if shinies spawn or not get removed in the emulation process?

Comment: When roms are created, they are essentially a copy of the original game in a format that can be executed by your device. So there should be no reason that this feature has changed.

Comment: @Ben ok, im glad to hear that. I was really hesitant because i didnt want to start soft resetting 3986 times and realize there werent any shinies in the rom XD

Comment: Interesting. I just asked a question similar to yours. I have done so much hunting for a shiny yet haven't found one and I'm on on myboy emulator too. I hope you find one and when you do, let me know so I don't give up hope. I have over 25000 between soft resets and random encounters and still no shiny.

Answer (score 4):

Shininess is determined by values inherent in the pokemon, so shinies are just as likely in an emulator.